# Как узнать список всех позиций слова в тексте python? Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Изучили следующее:

```
text1.index("monstrous")
```

Можем определить позицию когда первый раз встречается слово

```
list_numbers = [3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[i for i, n in enumerate(list_numbers) if n == 3
```

Можем использовать генерацию списков (list comprehension), чтобы узнать позиции совпадений в списке.
А как  сделать так, чтобы список всех позиций слова в тексте выводилось?

Comment: разбейте текст на слова, примените тот же enumerate, про который вы уже знаете и сравнивайте с искомым словом

Answer (score 0):

`.index()` очень похож на `.find()`, с одной разницей: `find` возвращает -1, если не находит подстроку, а `index` выдает ошибку.

Оба имеют еще два необязательных аргумента: [.find(подстрока[, от_позиции[, до_позиции]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

```
string = 'aaa aaa aaa aaa'
search = 'aaa'

L = []; index = 0

while True:
    index = string.find(search, index) # <-- можно указывать начальную позицию поиска
                                       # (предыдущий индекс + длина искомой подстроки)
    if index == -1: break

    L.append(index)
    index += len(search)

print( L ) # [0, 4, 8, 12]
```

Есть более компактный вариант, через модуль `re`:

```
import re

string = 'aaa aaa aaa aaa'
search = 'aaa'

L = [ match.start() for match in re.finditer(search, string) ]

print( L ) # [0, 4, 8, 12]
```